# Firefox does not gather ICE candidates unless the window is in focus?

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I'm testing my WebRTC app in Firefox, and it appears that Firefox is not gathering ICE candidates unless and until the Firefox window is in focus?! When using two separate browser windows on the same machine, one of them is obviously always not the frontmost window. The log tells me that Firefox stalls at the point where it's supposed to start gathering ICE candidates, until I explicitly click on the window to bring it into focus, at which point is starts candidate gathering and shortly after establishes the connection. I can switch windows any time after the process has started, it will finish successfully; but the window apparently must be in focus at the start of the process.

No such behaviour on Chrome, it always gathers candidates in any state.

Is this a known behaviour? Is there a rationale for this, or is it a bug?

*Firefox 44.0.2 on OS X El Cap*

Comment: Odd, it works fine for me in Firefox 44.0.2 with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v1Lnpmx/) opened in two tabs/windows. I'm also on OSX El Cap. Does that fiddle work for you?

Comment: I suppose it's possible in your application/framework to have a bug in event handling which could cause this.

Comment: @jesup The only thing that would explain this is if Object.defineProperty defined setters won't trigger in the background. Any idea about that? I'll have to test a bit more...

Comment: It worked for me on the same machine between Firefox 44.0.2 and Chrome, even when Chrome is in focus.

Comment: @jib That fiddle does in fact work for me. I'll look into this more closely...

Comment: It seems the problem is indeed not the ICE candidates, but the `getUserMedia` part blocks instead (which in turn won't start the ICE process...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden tabs or windows in Firefox cannot turn on the camera. Personally I feel a bit safer knowing that.

Even if you've chosen "Always Share", the camera wont activate until you focus the window.

From the comments it sounds like this is what's happening in your case.

In contrast, [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v1Lnpmx/) works fine from two tabs, because only the page where the user presses a button (the sender-side), accesses the camera.

```
This code section intentionally left blank.
```

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, it wasn't the ICE candidates, it was `getUserMedia` which blocks unless Firefox is the active window. The asynchronous nature of my code made this less apparent than it should have been. This behaviour is apparently by design and is described here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1195654.